# Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to capture data from the following text by regex:

Test string:

```
(003) Recoverable salaries and allowances (General)
(700) General non-recurrent, (001) lamslkdf; (999) ajkndsfk
```

And this is my current regex pattern

```
[\(|\[](?<code>[0-9]{0,3})[\)|\]]\s?(?<title>[\s\S]+)
```

This is my expectation and the above regex cannot match.

1. 003 >> Recoverable salaries and allowances (General)
2. 700 >> General non-recurrent
3. 001 >> lamslkdf
4. 999 >> ajkndsfk

How can I achieve this purpose? Please advice. Thanks

Comment: Please [use a descriptive title](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Try this expression: `(?<key>\(\d+\))(?<value>.*?)(?=(\(\d+\)|$))`

Comment: You don't seem to understand Regex syntax - what do you expect `[\(|\[]` to match? Also, your sample data does not include any `[` or `]` - what are you testing for those?

Comment: @NetMage, I would like to match the cases like [003] and (003)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cs
(?:\((?<code>\d{1,3})\)|\[(?<code>\d{1,3})])\s*(?<title>.*?)(?=\s*(?:\(\d{1,3}\)|\[\d{1,3}]|\z))
```

See [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3A%5C%28%28%3F%3Ccode%3E%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%29%5C%29%7C%5C%5B%28%3F%3Ccode%3E%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%29%5D%29%5Cs*%28%3F%3Ctitle%3E.*%3F%29%28%3F%3D%5Cs*%28%3F%3A%5C%28%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%5C%29%7C%5C%5B%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%5D%7C%5Cz%29%29&i=%28003%29%20Recoverable%20salaries%20and%20allowances%20%28General%29%0D%0A%28700%29%20General%20non-recurrent%2C%20%28001%29%20lamslkdf%3B%20%28999%29%20ajkndsfk). Output:

[image]

**Details**

- `(?:\((?<code>\d{1,3})\)|\[(?<code>\d{1,3})])` - either `(`, then one to three digits captures into Group "code", and `)`, or `[`, then 1-3 digits captured into Group "code" and `]`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?<title>.*?)` - Group "title"
- `(?=\s*(?:\(\d{1,3}\)|\[\d{1,3}]|\z))` - immediately followed with

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `(?:\(\d{1,3}\)|\[\d{1,3}]|\z)` - either `(` + one to three digits and `)`, or `[`, one to three digits, `]` or end of string.

Comment: Cool~ Thanks a lot. Regex makes me crazy.